# How can I send a DOM object as a JSON object

Tags: php, javascript, json, dom, stringify

I would like to POST an entire row of a table to a php page (it's part of an Ajax request). 
If I use `JSON.stringify(rowObject)` I get an error. I think this is because the object is "cyclical". I really would like to send the row though, because it has ALL the right data, as opposed to posting each variable individually. Is there a simple solutions that doesn't need jquery, or at least doesn't involve messily looping through the object and rebuilding it?

Comment: Could you post an example of the HTML for the row in text form (rowObject)?

Comment: Why JSON? Just serialize it to XML.

Comment: I know this isn't a debate about XML vs JSON, but each has their purpose. XML is great at being parsed on-the-fly, but it's fatter than JSON. If it's a quick, simple message, JSON is the bomb. If it's a huge amount of data, XML is probably a better choice, but it's all contextual.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I suggest posting not only an example of the DOM object's HTML, but the desired JSON format you want to convert to, and whether the JSON format is flexible.

Comment: here is what a row looks like:  
<tr id="issue-4">  
 <input type="hidden" value="2013-01-18 23:00:00">  
 <td>  
  <input type="hidden">3</input>  
  <select>  
   <option>1</option>  
   <option>2</option>  
   <option>3</option>  
   <option>4</option>  
   <option>5</option>  
  </select>  
 </td>  
 <td>  
  <input>  
  <button>Save</button>  
 </td>  
 <td>  
  <button>Close</button>  
  <input type="hidden" value="1">  
 </td>  
 <td title="Created: 2013-01-18 23:00:00">0000-00-00</td>  
</tr>

Comment: The error in chrome: TypeError: Accessing selectionDirection on an input element that cannot have a selection.

Answer (score 4):

[JSONML](http://www.jsonml.org) provides a nice markup representation as JSON data. It also [offers code](http://www.jsonml.org/dom/) for converting the DOM for you.

Given this DOM:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>one</th><th>two</th><th>three</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTbody">
        <tr><td><input value="one"/></td><td><span>two</span></td><td>three</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This code converts it to native JavaScript objects, and then to JSON:

```
var result = JsonML.fromHTML(document.querySelector("table"));
var strResult = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
```

And produces this result:

http://jsfiddle.net/bF3LK/

```
[
    "TABLE",
    "\n    ",
    [
        "THEAD",
        "\n        ",
        [
            "TR",
            [
                "TH",
                "one"
            ],
            [
                "TH",
                "two"
            ],
            [
                "TH",
                "three"
            ]
        ],
        "\n    "
    ],
    "\n    ",
    [
        "TBODY",
        {
            "id": "myTbody"
        },
        "\n        ",
        [
            "TR",
            [
                "TD",
                [
                    "INPUT",
                    {
                        "value": "one"
                    }
                ]
            ],
            [
                "TD",
                [
                    "SPAN",
                    "two"
                ]
            ],
            [
                "TD",
                "three"
            ]
        ],
        "\n    "
    ],
    "\n"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the row you want to fetch has id **rowID** the following should do what you asked

```
JSON.stringify(
    (function(o) {
        var arr=[];
        for(var x=0;x<o.length;x+=1) arr.push(o[x].innerText);
        return arr;
     }) (document.getElementById("rowID").getElementsByTagName("td")));
```

Comment: This is very much along the lines I was thinking. I might not write it the same way, but that's a good code example. :)

Comment: What would be the output of @the system's example? ... if someone is in it like in his own back yard and could post it easily.. :-)

Comment: @sasha see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1fd97pro/ note I added "rowID" as id of the row I want to fetch text from. As you run it you'll notice that no text is extracted from the first column (because it contains an input field and not text) - If the table contains input fields and data has to be fetched from those the code needs to be changed a little bit. but it's quite simple...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest iterating on the elements in the DOM object and building an object dynamically. Then you could JSON.stringify() that safely. It would be good to have more info about the DOM object and your desired JSON output to determine the best way to accomplish this.

Short of having that information, here are some suggestions.

Assuming rowObject is a DOM object, perhaps obtained using document.getElementById() or some other DOM method, you have access to a couple useful properties that return string values.

rowObject.textContent will give you a text-only version of your DOM object, leaving out the HTML tags but preserving whitespace.

rowObject.innerText is similar, but should exclude anything that is not visible.

rowObject.innerHTML will pull out the inner HTML and output the HTML tags and their contents.

I know this isn't the same as converting to true JSON. Again, it would be preferable to build an object dynamically that could then be passed to JSON.stringify().

For more information on these properties, see: [Node.textContent on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
    <td>row 0 cell 0</td>
    <td>row 0 cell 1</td>
    <td>row 0 cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 1 cell 0</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var data = [].map.call(table1.rows, function(row){
    return [].map.call(row.cells, function(cell){
        return cell.textContent; 
    });
});
console.log(data);
```

You will get the data json like this:

```
[
    [
        "row 0 cell 0",
        "row 0 cell 1",
        "row 0 cell 2"
    ],
    [
        "row 1 cell 0",
        "row 1 cell 1",
        "row 1 cell 2"
    ]
]
```